# CN1 how to deal with the home indicator (iPhone X and such)

Tags: codenameone

When we have to deal with (native) device specific objects on the display (such as the home indicator in iPhone X) in case of having a proper layout of our app (avoiding those objects violate the layout), should I adapt the layout in native code or in CN1 specific code?
What would you suggest?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of our effort was around the notch and not so much on the home button but we probably should add support for [iOS's safe area API](https://medium.com/rosberryapps/ios-safe-area-ca10e919526f). Although technically it's a pretty horrible API.

It might be better to add some device detection to the tabs component and add some padding in the bottom of the tabs by default. We can probably do it if you file an issue, you can do this manually too using a library such as [this](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/lightweight-picker-device-detection.html).