# How to leave white space for the iPhone X task switch bar at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: codenameone

The bottom navigation bar (the long horizontal bar at the bottom of the iPhone X screen which allows you to quickly switch between apps) overlaps with the bottom content of the Form.

I’ve tried googling for how to avoid this but haven’t found anything.

Is there a recommended approach or some built-in support in Codename One?

Comment: This was asked before here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53871747/cn1-how-to-deal-with-the-home-indicator-iphone-x-and-such
Unfortunately not much has changed since then as no issue was filed. I suggest filing an issue on this so we can address it and provide support for this.

Comment: OK, thanks for the feedback. I've created a bug #2946 (I would think this topic is urgent since it may be really annoying on all recent Apple devices).